# How to generate an excel on a blank page with EPPLUS and .net mvc?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

Good afternoon I would like you to help me generate the excel on a white page as a consolidated one that cannot be modified and can only be printed since mine downloads it in the browser but does not show it on a blank page.I thank in advance

**controller**

```
public ActionResult ExportarExcel(string IdProyecto, string fechaDesde, string fechaHasta)
        {

            DynamicDataTable Parametros = new DynamicDataTable();

            List<Sigeri> listado = GestionSigeri.Instancia.ListarSigeri(IdProyecto, fechaDesde, fechaHasta, Parametros.iDisplayLength, Parametros.iDisplayStart);

            var ruta =  new FileInfo("D:\\archivo_excel\\reporte_horas.xlsx");
            ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage(ruta);
            //ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Reportes");
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets["Gestion_horas"];

            ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Comunicación";
            ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "Com1";

            ws.Cells["A2"].Value = "Reporte";
            ws.Cells["B2"].Value = "Seguimiento de Horas";

            ws.Cells["A3"].Value = "Fecha";
            ws.Cells["B3"].Value = string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy} at {0:H:  mm tt}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

            ws.Cells["A6"].Value = "PROYECTO";
            ws.Cells["B6"].Value = "DESCRIPCION";
            ws.Cells["C6"].Value = "HORAS";
            ws.Cells["D6"].Value = "T. COBRADO";
            ws.Cells["E6"].Value = "COSTO BIENES";
            ws.Cells["F6"].Value = "MANO OBRA";
            ws.Cells["G6"].Value = "GASTOS GENERALES";
            ws.Cells["H6"].Value = "DEPRECIACION";

            int rowstart = 7;

            foreach (Sigeri obj in listado)
            {
                ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.Proyecto.IdProyecto; //obj.Proyecto.IdProyecto; //obj.Proyecto.IdProyecto;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("B{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.Proyecto.Descripcion;//obj.Proyecto.Descripcion;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("C{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.Horas;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("D{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.TotalCobrado;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("E{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.CostoBienes;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("F{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.ManoObra;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("G{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.GatosGenerales;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("H{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.Depreciacion;
                rowstart++;

            }

            var myChart = ws.Drawings.AddChart("chart", eChartType.Line);


            //Define las series para el cuadro
            var series = myChart.Series.Add("C7: E7", "C6: E6");
            myChart.Border.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            myChart.Title.Text = "My Chart";
            myChart.SetSize(500, 400);

            //Agregar a la 6ta fila y a la 6ta columna
            myChart.SetPosition(6, 0, 10, 0);

            //myChart.ChartType = eChartType.ColumnClustered;
            var myChart2 = myChart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(eChartType.ColumnClustered);
            //Define las series para el cuadro
            var series2 = myChart2.Series.Add("C7: E7", "C6: E6");

            //Agregar a la 6ta fila y a la 6ta columna
            myChart2.SetPosition(6, 0, 10, 0);

            ws.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            pkg.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            //memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            //memoryStream.Close();
            //Response.End();
            return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { FileDownloadName = "Gestion_horas.xlsx" };
        }
```

The previous code exports an excel in the browser but does not show it on a blank page.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnExportar">Exportar Excel</a>
```

js method that calls the @url.action of the controller

```
$("#btnExportar").click(function () {
    exportar();
});


exportar=function () {
    const Idproyecto = $("#IdProyecto").val();
    var fechaDesde = $("#fechaDesde").val();
    var fechaHasta = $("#fechaHasta").val();

    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:56450/Sigeri/ExportarExcel?IdProyecto=' + Idproyecto + '&fechaDesde=' + fechaDesde + '&fechaHasta=' + fechaHasta+'';

}
```

Comment: sorry not a @ url.action simply a href

Answer (score 0):

Internet browsers generally do not have functionality built-in to display an Excel sheet.

If you want anyone to be able to view the contents of the Excel sheet, you will have to convert it to a HTML page. I suggest you look at these NuGet packages: [FreeSpire.XLS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.XLS) (commercial license) or [ExcelToHtml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelToHtml) (MIT license).